# How can I return an optional instead of throwing an exception?

Tags: java, exception, io, option-type

I have a method that can possibly throw an error. This exception is out of my control, as it is an IO exception, not a exception **I** am throwing. Instead of adding a throws statement to my method or fitting it in a try and catch block, would I be able to return an optional via this method?

Summary: I have a method to return a value T, except to get to that value, I have to add a try/catch block or throws statement to my method. Can I return an Optional of type T instead of throwing this error?

Comment: Yes, that would be one possible solution and will work provided all methods/classes that use your object know how to cope if the Optional returns false when you call `isPresent()`. This solution is really the same as simply returning a null object though and having the calling method check for null?

Comment: I was making a wrapper for an API, and I was planning on returning Optionals instead of throwing exceptions, as Optionals are WAY better as far as exception management goes. I am not 100% sure if #isPresent returns "false" if the Optional's value is null, which is why I made this post instead of just doing that.

Comment: Rather than changing the title to add SOLVED, the way to mark a question as resolved on Stack Overflow is to accept one of the answers. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: It's up to you to return Optional or throw an exception, and they can't be compared. Returning Optional is a better option if the caller does not need to know that a specific error has occurred and only cares about the result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*"Instead of adding a throws statement to my method or fitting it in a try and catch block"*

Well, those are your two options.  Either you can

- Catch the exception yourself and return an empty `Optional`. This is not a good idea as it hides the exception, OR
- You can let the exception propagate.
- I suppose a third option is to wrap the exception in an unchecked exception, but that just makes your interface murkier.

If you really want to defer error handling to the caller and not `throw`, the ideal solution is to implement a composite object to return, containing both the error status and the return value if there is one.

Comment: Does ```#isPresent()``` still return false if the Optional is null, or will it throw an exception? Also, thanks for the help, I appreciate it!

Comment: The value of an `Optional` is not allowed to be `null`. This is covered in the documentation for the class https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html

Comment: If the `Optional` itself is `null` (which should absolutely be avoided) then calling a method on it will throw a `NullPointerException`, just like calling any method on any type of `null` value would.

Comment: There is a 4th option: return null instead of Optional. This was the way to handle the absence of Optional before it was added. Checking that the return is null or the Optional.isPresent() seems pretty close.

Comment: @hidralisk That approach discards the exception altogether, which is never a good option as it hinders troubleshooting unless you take extra steps to log the exception somewhere.

Comment: @TimMoore that is what I was thinking, which is why I wasn't sure if #isPresent would work; Is there any way I can stuff a value of, essentially nothing, into an optional? I think I could just declare an optional and using the #empty method of Optional after the equals sign?

Comment: Yes, `Optional.empty()` is the correct way to indicate an absent value with `Optional`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use code like this to wrap code that returns a value with something that captures exceptions and returns an empty optional:

```
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.function.Supplier;

@FunctionalInterface
public interface ThrowingSupplier<T> extends Supplier<Optional<T>> {
    @Override
    default Optional<T> get() {
        return getCapturingExceptions(this);
    }

    T getOrThrow() throws Exception;

    static <U> Optional<U> getCapturingExceptions(ThrowingSupplier<U> supplier) {
        try {
            return Optional.ofNullable(supplier.getOrThrow());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return Optional.empty();
        }
    }
}
```

Examples of use:

```
import org.junit.Test;

import java.util.Optional;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

public class ThrowingSupplierTest {
    @Test
    public void testSuccessfulSupplier() {
        assertEquals(
                Optional.of("Successful"),
                ThrowingSupplier.getCapturingExceptions(() -> "Successful")
        );
    }

    @Test
    public void testThrowingSupplier() {
        assertEquals(
                Optional.empty(),
                ThrowingSupplier.getCapturingExceptions(() -> {
                    throw new Exception("Expected failure; will be logged but test should pass");
                })
        );
    }
}
```

This has all of the disadvantages outlined in Jim Garrison's answer, and I would agree with him that it is usually better to allow exceptions to propagate (wrapping in an unchecked exception when necessary). Still, this  is sometimes useful. For example, if you need to implement an interface that doesn't allow for a checked exception, and allowing an unchecked exception to propagate up the call stack would have undesirable effect such as killing a thread that doesn't handle them properly. To that end, this example implements `Supplier` (which cannot throw an unchecked exception) and can be used anywhere that interface is expected.

A few changes you might want to make:

1. This logs caught exceptions using `e.printStackTrace()`. It is important not to completely lose the exception message and stack trace, but if your application uses a logging framework, you might prefer to log the exception using that.
2. It uses `Optional.ofNullable` on the assumption that the wrapped code might return `null`, which isn't allowed in an `Optional`. This means that it might return an empty `Optional` even if no exception occurred. If the original code is not expected to return `null`, this could be changed to `Optional.of`. However if the wrapped code does return `null` in that case, `Optional.of` will throw a `NullPointerException`, which will be caught by the `catch` block and result in an empty `Optional` returned regardless.

It should also be noted that if the wrapped code returns an `Optional` type itself, this will be wrapped in another `Optional` layer. Getting the underlying value will require unwrapping it twice.