# How to easily convert Exception to Optional.empty()

Tags: java, option-type

I notice that in a lot of code I'm not interested in the Exception that is thrown in a called method. I just want to get an Optional if it succeeds, and an empty() if not.

Is there something similar to ofNullable, but then instead an *ofThrowable*, where I pass a function reference? Then I could do something like:

```
myOptionalString.flatMap(ofThrowable(Integer::parseInt))
```

Comment: not that I know of, but nobody is stopping you from creating a static method that catches an exception and returns `Optional.empty()` instead.

Comment: I can, but that would be so generic that I would expect it to be in Optional itself. I was hoping there's already a common(s) library that has it.

Comment: It is a questionable idea, since swallowing exceptions is considered a bad practice. I totally understand your use case, I just wouldn't expect the OpenJDK community to happily provide such a method. They would tell you to use filter instead `Optional.of(yourString).filter(this::isValidNumber).map(Integer::parseInt)`

Comment: @JAsgarov no need to vendor provide such method to catching exception, indeed you can simple add as many method as you want to stream api :), https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48010544/how-do-i-write-a-custom-stream-function

Comment: @JAsgarov I disagree that this would "swallow" the Exception. It would just convert one type ("Try") into another (Optional), something that is very common in a language like Scala.

Comment: @JeroenKransen provided there is only one execution flow that results in an empty Optional your point is valid. But if there is an alternative flow that also results in empty Optional as well, user wouldn't know if an exception took place and hence it was swallowed. One might argue a different type of Optional might be needed to express this situation e.g. `Optional.exception()`

Comment: I think this https://stackoverflow.com/a/71059020/2886891 answers your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The library [`throwing-function`](https://github.com/pivovarit/throwing-function) implements that functionality.

In pom.xml:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.pivovarit</groupId>
        <artifactId>throwing-function</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

To use it:

```java
import static com.pivovarit.function.ThrowingFunction.lifted;

[...]

myOptionalString.flatMap(lifted(Integer::parseInt))
```

PS. I'm not the library author; I don't know them and they doesn't know me.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to surround the ofThrowable(or generally the piece of code you trying to catch the exception) with try catch and return desired optional as return value of each block,

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        yourOptional.flatMap(o ->
        {
            try {
                return Optional.of(ofThrowable(Integer::parseInt, o));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return Optional.empty();
            }
        });
    }

    public static Integer ofThrowable(Function<String, Integer> extractor, Integer value) throws Exception {
        //some logic perhaps
        throw new Exception();
    }
}
```

Indeed you can add whole try catch as method and add it to [Stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71122628/how-to-easily-convert-exception-to-optional-empty/71123139#71123139) api.

Comment: I was not looking for something that would work, that's trivial. I was looking for something that is elegant. Having blocks of code inside a Stream obfuscates the flow and defeats its purpose imho.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest/most elegant way I know is to wrap it with [vavr](https://docs.vavr.io/#_try) scala-like `Try` that will catch and convert it to a `Failure` that can be easily changed to an empty `Optional` -

```
Optional<Whatever> result = Try.of(() -> mayThrowAnException()).toJavaOptional();
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be easy to create such a wrapper method yourself:

```
final class Exceptions {
  private Exceptions() {}

  static <R> R asNull(final Callable<? extends R> action) {
    try {
      return action.call();
    } catch (final Exception ex) {
      return null;
    }
  }
}

final class Optionals {
  private Optionals() {}

  static <T, R> Function<T, R> exceptionToNull(final ThrowingFunction<? super T, ? extends R> f) {
    return v -> Exceptions.asNull(() -> f.apply(v));
  }

  static <T, R> Function<T, Optional<R>> exceptionToEmpty(final ThrowingFunction<? super T, ? extends R> f) {
    return Optionals.<T, R>exceptionToNull(f).andThen(Optional::ofNullable);
  }

  @FunctionalInterface
  interface ThrowingFunction<T, R> {
    R apply(T t) throws Exception;
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
    System.out.println(Optional.of("string").flatMap(Optionals.exceptionToEmpty(Integer::parseInt)));
    System.out.println(Optional.of("123").flatMap(Optionals.exceptionToEmpty(Integer::parseInt)));
    System.out.println(Optional.of("string").map(Optionals.exceptionToNull(Integer::parseInt)));
    System.out.println(Optional.of("123").map(Optionals.exceptionToNull(Integer::parseInt)));
    System.out.println(Exceptions.asNull(() -> Integer.parseInt("string")));
    System.out.println(Exceptions.asNull(() -> Integer.parseInt("123")));

    Stream.of("string", "123")
        .map(Optional::of)
        .map(o -> o.flatMap(Optionals.exceptionToEmpty(Integer::parseInt)))
        .forEach(System.out::println);

    Stream.of("string", "123")
        .map(Optional::of)
        .map(o -> o.map(Optionals.exceptionToNull(Integer::parseInt)))
        .forEach(System.out::println);

    Stream.of("string", "123")
        .map(s -> Exceptions.asNull(() -> Integer.parseInt(s)))
        .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Not saying ignoring/swallowing exceptions is a good idea, but it's certainly possible.